# Spring Boot Hibernate not picking up use-new-id-generator-mappings property

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-5.x, sequence-generators, hilo

I'm upgrading my project to Spring Boot 2.1.18 that uses Hibernate 5.3.18.

Previously, my entity looked like thus and would use the SequenceHiLoGenerator:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_link")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "group_link_seq", sequenceName = "group_link_seq")
public class GroupLinkEntity extends BaseObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "group_link_seq")
    @Column(name = "group_link_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id 
}
```

Now, by default in Hibernate 5, it uses the SequenceStyleGenerator which causes constraint violations because my increment size is 1 and the default allocationSize is 50.

The suggested thing to do to maintain compatibility is to set this property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
```

I do so but it does not seem to take, because the SequenceStyleGenerator is still used. From my understanding, this should cause it to use the SequenceHiLoGenerator. Is this incorrect?

However, if I modify the entity to look like the below it works as expected, replicating the previous functionality I had.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_link")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "group_link_seq",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator",
                parameters = {
                           @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "group_link_seq"),
                           }
       )
public class GroupLinkEntity extends BaseObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "group_link_seq")
    @Column(name = "group_link_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    
}
```

So, it would seem the property is not being taken somehow and I'm looking to figure out why that is. I see it show up in my JpaProperties bean. If I change other properties, like my dialect, I can see that they are taking effect.

Could anyone point me to the code that actually reads that property and makes a decision on what generator to use or point out some obvious error I'm making here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties):

> You need to ensure that names defined under `spring.jpa.properties.*` exactly match those expected by your JPA provider. Spring Boot will not attempt any kind of relaxed binding for these entries.
>
> For example, if you want to configure Hibernate’s batch size you must use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`. If you use other forms, such as `batchSize` or `batch-size`, Hibernate will not apply the setting.

So, for your case you should use:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: false
```

See also [this part](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-mapping) of hibernate documentation.

Comment: Sigh. Thank you. I must have been blind to the difference.

Comment: I know it is a bit late for questions, but what is the difference between `jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: false` and `jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings: false`? Because with your answers everything works, but with use-new-id-generator-mappings: false don't. I am confused because there are a lot of people on Internet which make they applications work with both. I am using Hibernate 5 with Spring v1.5.6.RELEASE.

Comment: `jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings` just invalid property name according to the mentioned documentation.